# Textarea Resizes On Focus

Tags: javascript, html, css

Whenever I click on the textarea, everything is thrown off balance. Even though I have used min-height and width in the css, the textarea seems to grow/shrink unexpectedly. I have also turned resize off, but that still does nothing. Instead of using rows and cols, I have decided to use width and height in order to have equal element sizes between computer screen sizes.

Link to Code: http://urlext.net/LiylWR
(Link had to be shortened since jsbin output wasn't allowed in Stack overflow without code; which is huge by the way!)

Comment: What browser are you using? Can you screencap what your issue is? I'm not seeing any change in the textarea when clicked on my end in Chrome.

Comment: Unable to reproduce problem described in Firefox either.  Please read [How to create a minimal and complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to post code in the question. It takes work on your part but makes answering easier. Cutting out stuff that is not related to the error can also solve the  problem in many cases

Comment: Reproducible under IE11, but its very light (2 or 3 pixels)

Comment: Just checked on another computer (on Chrome) and have noticed no problems. This is what I saw when I first experienced the error on my 15" laptop: https://imagebin.ca/v/3j7bFsp59eGX